# How to add the strategy type in boost::within

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am using the boost library to check point in polygon using the within function.

I am testing using the code example provided at boost website. I want to change the strategy type.

The documentation says "If a point is located exactly on the border of a geometry, the result depends on the strategy. The default strategy (Winding (coordinate system agnostic)) returns false in that case."

I want points on borders to be considered within. Which strategy should I use? 
How can I add the strategy type?

I tried testing with the franklin strategy type but could not add it, below code gives this error:

> error C2039: 'get': is not a member of 'boost::geometry::core_dispatch::access,double,1,boost::integral_constant>'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <string> 

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/strategies/cartesian/point_in_poly_franklin.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::segment<point_type> seg;
    typedef boost::geometry::strategy::within::franklin<point_type, seg, void> fran;

    std::string str;
    fran fran_;

    polygon_type poly;

    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7)(2 1.3)(4.0 2.0, 4.2 1.4, 4.8 1.9, 4.4 2.2, 4.0 2.0))", poly);

    point_type p(4, 1);

    std::cout << "within: " << (boost::geometry::within(p, poly,fran_) ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second template parameter for `strategy::within::franklin` is wrong, it expects a point type, you passed a segment type. You could probably use `covered_by` to achieve what you want. [Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ulDxKYej8VGBSs3I).

Comment: Thanks a lot! So to detect both cases (in polygon & on boundary) I should OR the results of both methods (within and covered_by). If you would like to write it as an answer I'll vote for correctness.

Comment: `covered_by` seems to do that by itself: ["covered_by

Checks if the first geometry is inside or on border the second geometry."](http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/covered_by/covered_by_2.html). Feel free to make an answer yourself, I don't have time at the moment.